# Why k-means clustering is used in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

Why it is used as we can simply segment image components out by pixel intensity values?
Like if I want to extract skin of a girl and her hair, i can simply do this on pixel intensity values, rather than by using complicated k-means algorithm.

Comment: Not when you don't know the intensity of the skin and hair beforehand ! The K-means will choose them for you (provided they cover a sufficiently large area on the image).

Comment: Why those downvotes for a perfectly reasonable question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust because you could simply google k-means image processing to find plenty of answers and examples? the question basically says: I'm too lazy too spend 10 minutes on reading, could someone else please spend 15 minutes to boil it down to a nice answer?

Comment: @Piglet: maybe. The question is not "how does one compute the K-means", the question is more "what is it that I don't understand", for which no googling can help. I keep thinking that the downvotes are undue. Anyway, when I see the answer that was accepted by the OP (absolutely not about automatic threshold computation), I wonder if he even understood his own question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust i accepted because I want to earn reputation and for ethics, otherwise my instructor helped me in actually understanding my problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segmentation is not simple. Clustering is easier and more robust than manually thresholding.

Let's take a look using Matlab:

[image: yellow lily]

The areas of interest are the yellow petals. Let's divide the rgb-image into three different planes:

```
lily = imread('yellowlily.jpg')

redplane = lily(:,:,1);
greenplane = lily(:,:,2);
blueplane = lily(:,:;3);

imshow(greenplane); colormap(jet); imcontrast;
```

Viewing the greenplane:

[image: greenplane of the image]

So the yellow is actually more 'green' than the green? Uh oh. Well no matter, let's just combine the threshold. Yellow is strong in the redplane and the greenplane, so two thresholds to find it. Green is strong in green, on the other hand the background is black and has high values in all of them. So two thresholds for yellow, one for green but not black or yellow, so three comparisons for green..? And that is until the lighting changes a bit and wrecks our manual thresholds completely.

Or instead we could try out the clustering:

```
redIndices = redPlane(:);
greenIndices = greenPlane(:);
blueIndices = bluePlane(:);

Data = [redIndices, blueIndices, greenIndices];
clusterIdx = kmeans(Data,3);    

ClusterImage = zeros(size(RedPlane));
ClusterImage(:) = clusterIdx;
```

[image]

Almost there. We got the yellow petals, the green failed, black needs some morphological love. Just one parameter, the number of clusters. Maybe a Gaussian Mixture model as a soft K-means?

One more point to consider would be overlapping colors, such as the green near the bases of the yellow petals. The girl whose hair you are segmenting might be standing near some trees with the same brown in their bark. You can add distance in the image as one dimension of the data, in e.g. the GMM I mentioned earlier. The concept of distance in the color space and the image can be a powerful and a robust segmentation tool, something which manual thresholds can never be.